# Keycloak and SSO with SAML and Safari

Tags: keycloak, sfauthenticationsession

we are using keycloak 3.4.2 to try to integrate SSO behavior (via SAML). I configured two clients in the same realm; if user logins to clientA and he opens a new tab in the same browser and logins to clientB he is successfully automatically logged in.

But we are trying to integrate the following behavior: 
- from ipad user opens safari and goes to site A
- he logins to site A successfully
- from site A he clicks an "universal link" to open an app previously installed which is simply a webview to site B.

**Current result** is the user lands in the login page of the app.

**Expected result** is the user gets automatically logged in.

We are using iOS 11 for frontend. Both site A and site B have a backend side written in Java6.

Our idea was to reuse all cookies from site A to app with webview of site B by using an iOS widget "SFAuthenticationSession"; but once logged in the only cookie available is JSESSIONID which is not enough I think.
In my tests when I am using only a browser with different tabs, for each different tab I have a different JSESSIONID so I expect to have a different JSESSIONID when I am landing to site B.

Our approach has been taken from current source code:

https://github.com/dvdhpkns/SFAuthenticationSession-example

So what can we do to accomplish our task ?

What are we missing ? Do we need any other tokens/cookie ? How to retrieve them ? And when ?

I hope I clearly explained issue, sorry but authentication issues are not my strong point.